# Firebase user delete code not working from application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have used the following code after the button clicked event :

```
mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance.getCurrentUser();
mCurrentUser.delete.addOnCompleteListner(............)
```

and also used if and else statement for appropriate actions for the ***task*** to be done.

But nothing's happening in the application on that click event, also not deleting the firebase user account. Help me regarding this.

thank you.

Comment: You are probably getting an error which you are not inspecting. I also speculate the error is the requirement for recent login in order to delete the user.

Comment: yup that's the one thing i think thanks

Answer (score 1):

try with this answer, I had tried with this

```
 FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

user.delete()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User account deleted.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: please recheck your code it is working copy and it is copy of firebase documentation